# Apache goes down taking my sites offline

Tags: apache-2.2

My websites go offline several times a day. I can still go in to my WHM in cpanel. I hit the restart apache button and everything comes back online in seconds.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What do the log files say about it crashing? Check /var/log/messages, /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log, /usr/local/apache/domlogs/{domain}/

Comment: @frogstarr78 I looked at the logs and I see someone trying to access /home/t8pjgwzt/public_html/phpmyadmin and db about 50 times a second. Clearly a hacker. Could the load be causing this?

Comment: @frogstarr78 Hum, I see this? [Sat Oct 08 15:07:55 2011] [notice] child pid 26406 exit signal Aborted (6)
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: free(): invalid pointer: 0x08d79b50 ***

Comment: you mention cpanel - is this a shared host? Do you have root access to the underlying machine hosting cpanel? If not you're prob better off contacting the hosting provider as you won't be able to change/fix much from within cpanel

Comment: @iainlbc I rent a dedicated server from Godaddy with cpanel installed. I do have root access and Godaddy is really no help. Had them inspect my drive last week and they left my server offline.

Comment: Are most of your sites database-based? And what type errors are you seeing from your sites?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding apache using easyapache in WHM?

Comment: @recluze Yes, I did the rebuild twice.

Comment: @Rilindo yes, all the sites run on a MySql database.

Comment: How is the server and io load? Is the server pegged CPU or memory-wise, or do you have spare capacity available?

Comment: @RilindoIm starting to see this in my logs , does this mean anything? *** glibc detected *** /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: free(): invalid pointer: 0x09d76f80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x31f6c5]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0x31fb09]
/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd(CRYPTO_free+0x25)[0x81332b5]
[0x9d14008]
======= Memory map: ========
00101000-00223000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 13697975   /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.36.0
00223000-0022b000 rwxp 00121000 08:03 13697975   /usr/lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There certainly seems to be some memory corruption going on. If that corruption only hits the children your main apache process might survive... provided you don't use something like the threaded process model which shares the code between all apache processes. Your question is tagged both apache1 and apache2, even for this first paragraph I choose to believe you're not running the ancient 1.x version... :)

If the main process (with the "old" but trusty pre-spawned child process model) is corrupted it might be hardware - bad memory or actual corrupted code on your disk... else a child process could theoretically corrupt the parent process as well. Check your modules as well, since the corrupted code could be there.

Whatever the reason, I hope you keep your apache up to date - there are quite some security holes being fixed on an almost daily basis, and since webservers are the #1 attack vector that can't be stressed enough. There's also [good advice](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm) about how to harden your apache configuration, even from the [apache project itself](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html).

Btw. the phpmyadmin attacks you are seeing are probably not an attack on your server but an XSS attack on some other server. Anyway, [this list](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-784/Phpmyadmin.html) should help you if you actually run phpmyadmin.

Answer (score -4):

In my opinion

Some other service is also trying to use the port of apache.
try to find that service and stop that service.

Comment: If another service tried to take over a port that is currently in use, it would just fail. It would not hijack the port.